# Pycharm on Mac: why Python SDK cache get corrupted regularly?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, virtualenv

This is the massage that Pycharm gives me almost once a day, and I have to restart it. As I have multiple projects open, it gives this error for each virtualenv repeatedly until I force quit it.

Is there a way to prevent Pycharm from constantly invalidating cache?

#ps: I never had such issues with Pycharm on Windows

> **Invalid Python SDK**
>
> Cannot set up a python SDK at Python 3.9 (demographics-g5XoraTQ) (/Users/mamad/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/up-demographics-g5XoraTQ-py3.9/bin/python). The SDK seems invalid.

[image: pycharm error]

Comment: See if [one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpycharm%5d%20Invalid%20Python%20SDK&searchOn=3) addresses the problem. This hasn't happened to me so I don't know what the solution would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was the number of git repositories each with a separate project SDK (i.e. venv interpreter) that I had simultaneously opened in my PyCharm instance (over 10).

The re-indexing of git caches and Python libraries created memory issues and eventually resulted in corruption of index files; this couldn't be solved unless I restarted my PyCharm instance once a day.

The solution was to:

- Either re-use one virtual environment for all projects; which is not desirable at all.
- Or, as soon as I am done with a project, remove the project along with its Python interpreter and git repository from PyCharm. To speed things up, I set my Poetry to create its `.venv` inside the project folder; so interpreter and project both can be removed in a single command.

One undesirable outcome of the second solution is that my shell now displays one `venv` name for all my virtual environments in all project folders.